# Can I use only 2 of 3 displays with VMWare Fusion? OSX host, Win8.1 guest

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I am using VMWare Fusion 7.1.3, OSX 10.10.5, and Windows 8.1 on my MacBook pro 13" (early 2015) with 2 external displays.

I want to have Windows full screen on the two external displays, leaving the built-in display free to run Mac apps. The problem is that VMWare only gives me options for "single display" full screen and "all displays" full screen.

I tried using "all displays" and then telling windows to ignore the laptop display, but VMWare intervened and instantly reverted the setting back to using all 3.

I tried to simply change the desktop space, but whenever VMWare/Windows takes focus all 3 monitors switch to full screen.

Is there a way to tell VMWare to only use specific displays rather than all 3?

Comment: As of moving on to Sierra, I am facing this problem too. Very frustrating to have this problem after upgrading from a perfectly stable work environment. Good ol' work policies.

Comment: Same problem here too would love to find an answer for this