# How to use a specified number of monitors in VMware Fusion in macOS

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, display-settings

This has been asked many times before, with the solution being fairly straightforward (e.g. Settings > Display, etc). Currently, VMware Fusion 10 provides an option to use *all* monitors in fullscreen mode.

*View > Use all displays in fullscreen*

This is useful if you want dual monitor support when you have two physical external monitors. However, I typically work with *three* external monitors and only want to use two of them for my guest virtual machine.

Is this possible? It seems previous versions of VMware allowed the user to explicitly set the number of monitors passed to the guest, but the latest release (10) seems like an "all or nothing" approach.

Comment: It's at least the same in version 8. See also https://superuser.com/questions/1048326/can-i-use-only-2-of-3-displays-with-vmware-fusion-osx-host-win8-1-guest

Comment: @madz I reached out to the development team via their forums and was told this is not possible to do currently. It was taken down as a requested feature for future releases.

Comment: Thanks for the update - do you have a link to the thread I will go and +1

Comment: @sherrellbc I know this is old but do you by chance have a link to that forum post? I'm on v8 and have no reason to upgrade until/unless this is implemented so I'd like to bug them on it too.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? I have the same requirement. I have 2 external monitors connected to my MBP, and I am using VMWare Fusion 12.1.0 to run Linux PopOS. However, I want the VM to use only 2 of 3 monitors so that I can run Mac applications on my 3rd monitor.